# How to save to and read from a NSObject

Tags: ios, nsstring, uiimage, nsobject, nsset

I have two NSObject's.

```
@interface Car : NSObject{
     @property (strong) NSSet *cars;
}
```

and

```
@interface Model : NSObject{
     @property (strong) UIImage *picture;
     @property (strong) NSString *name;
}
```

Basically the object Car has a NSSet cars and each object of the NSSet cars has the properties picture and name.

How can I relate this two NSObject's and how can I save a string or image to the Car NSSet using the properties of the Model NSObject. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easy adding or removing, your "`cars`" property should be declared as a [NSMutableSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html).

And assuming your single Car object is named "`listOfCars`", here is one way to do what (I think) you are trying to do:

```
Model * newModel = [[Model alloc] init];
if(newModel)
{
    newModel.picture = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Edsel.jpg"];
    newModel.name = @"Ugly Car";

    [listOfCars.cars addObject: newModel];
}
```

And, in your Car .m file, do something like this:

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        _cars = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    }
    return(self);
}
```

The init method is the *only* place you should be referring to the underlying variable for your "`cars`" property.  Everywhere else it should be "`listOfCars.cars`" or "`self.cars`" if you're referring to the cars set from within the Car object.

Comment: Ahah is in fact an ugly car! I think this works but I can't seem to view the content of listOfCars.cars just to make sure, it gives me null. I'm trying `NSLog(@"%@", listOfCars.cars);`

Comment: right, the "`cars`" set needs to alloc'd.  I've modified my code.

Comment: I had already did the alloc of the mutableSet. It still gives me the null value. If I do `NSLog(@"%@", newModel.name)` it gives me the right string so it saves. But the `listOfCars.cars` gives me null. Maybe I have to do a different NSLog to view the objects.

Comment: how are you declaring your "`listOfCars`" Car object in your code?

Comment: I'm using `self.cars = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];` And I'm trying the `NSLog(@"%@", self.cars)`;

Comment: Now it gives me something. When I NSLog it shows `{( <Model: 0x718eb70> )}`. There is something there but how can I log it correctly to see whats inside?

Comment: well... your Model object has two properties and one of them is a string.  Try doing a NSLog on the string?